# Best way to check input parameter isnullorwhitespace in tbv function

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, rdbms

I have a TBV function. And that function getting   couple of input parameters.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn]
(
 @id NVARCHAR(50),
 ...
 ...
)
```

For example i want to check that *@id* is not null and is not whitespace.

I was  tinking to do like this

```
SELECT * FROM [FN_Table]() WHERE
COALESCE(@Id,'') !='' AND NULLIF(@id,'') !=null AND @Id=Id
```

But this is a tedious way i am sure that there would be more elegant and effective way i just newbbe in SQL and do not know best practices.

Comment: You could use `@Id <> N''` if your definition of whitespace is an empty string or all spaces.

Comment: What about just use coalesce something like this

Coalesce(@string, ' ') != ' ' 

 would no this solve the both problems?

Comment: Since a compare to `NULL` results in `UNKNOWN` instead of true or false, `@Id <> N''` will not be true when `@id` is `NULL` so this solves both problems (NULL and whitespace as spaces). Any value that is not null and not all spaces will evaluate to true.

Answer (score 1):

If you want `id` to be not null or white space, you can use `ltrim()`:

```
where ltrim(@id) <> ''
```

This does the `NULL` check as well, implicitly.

I'm not sure why you have a comparison to zero.  Based on your question this is not necessary.  If you are passing in numbers, you should not be using a string type.

Comment: That was a mistake from my side.I have  change the code.Thx

Comment: Why use LTRIM? Wouldn't `@id <> N''` do the job?

Comment: @DanGuzman . . . Not if the string contains spaces . . . "and not whitespace".

Comment: Trailing spaces are ignored in SQL Server comparison so wouldn't `N'   ' <> N''` evaluate to false as will `LTRIM(N'   ') <> N''`? `LTRIM` removes only spaces, not other whitespace like tabs and new-lines.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Check with `ISNULL` and then Get `BlankSpace Character Index`

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN ISNULL(@ID,'')='' THEN 1
WHEN CHARINDEX(' ',@ID) >0 THEN 1
ELSE 0
END
```